# DNN8 - ?mode=InstallResources no longer working

Tags: dotnetnuke

Back in the DNN7 (and earlier) days I was able to insert multiple extensions in the ../dnn/Install/Module folder, and navigating to:

http://localhostdnnsite/install/install.aspx?mode=InstallResources

would attempt automatically install any modules in that folder.  I've recently attempted to install the latest version of DNN, and it doesn't seem to know this path anymore.  I know they've fixed a lot of security vulnerabilities with the installwizard page, etc. but is there a different way to easily install multiple modules at once, or was this removed completely?  I can't find any information on it, and there are some semi-recent posts that indicate that this should work, but I'm not convinced (since it doesn't seem to, at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found *a* solution that will work for now, but hopefully a more permanent  solution is put in place in the near future.  You can simply copy these 3 files:

- install.aspx
- install.aspx.cs
- DotNetNuke.install.config.resources

in to the **../dnnfolder/Install** folder (i.e. from an older DNN installation) and the automatic module installation will work.

Comment: I haven't tried that myself in a while, but I would caution you on this approach. Those files were removed because of the security vulnerabilities that were found in DNN over the past year. You definitely want to be careful with leaving them there.

Comment: Agreed - it is definitely not an ideal solution and my thought would be to only put them there when module updates are necessary, and remove them immediately after.  Thanks for the warning, though.